# How to make Raspbian "Wheezy" boot to command line

Tags: networking, raspbian-wheezy

When I first set up my raspberry pi, I changed the settings to make it boot to the GUI automatically. Is there anyway for me to undo this, and make it boot to the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just start the config tool again and disable it

```
$ sudo raspi-config
```